# Elasticsearch 7.13 aggregations multi_terms with array values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have this structure of data

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "info": {
            "languages": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "English"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Arabic"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "Hindi"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So I have used "aggregations" like this

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
         "languages": {
            "multi_terms": {
                "size": 10000,
                "terms": [
                    {
                        "field": "info.languages.id"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "info.languages.name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I got these results

```
"languages": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": [
                        10,
                        "english"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "10|english",
                    "doc_count": 147356
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        10,
                        "hindi"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "10|hindi",
                    "doc_count": 58075
                },
                {
                    "key": [
                        11,
                        "hindi"
                    ],
                    "key_as_string": "26|hindi",
                    "doc_count": 58075
                } ....
```

I need to return something like this

"languages": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
"sum_other_doc_count": 0,
"buckets": [
{
"key": [
10,
"english"
],
"key_as_string": "10|english",
"doc_count": 147356
},
{
"key": [
11,
"hindi"
],
"key_as_string": "26|hindi",
"doc_count": 58075
} ....

Thank you

Comment: WHat is the difference between your expected search result and the search result which you are getting ?

Comment: @ESCoder if I have record with 2 languages so the result will be something like this
"key_as_string": "10|english", "doc_count": 1 ... 
"key_as_string": "10|hindi", "doc_count": 1 ..... 
"key_as_string": "11|english", "doc_count": 1 ..... 
"key_as_string": "11|hindi", "doc_count": 1 ......  

but i need the result like this
"key_as_string": "10|english", "doc_count": 1
 .... 
"key_as_string": "11|hindi", "doc_count": 1
 ...